# simple graphs of degree 16 with a semiregular normal subgroup isomorphic to the quaternion group $Q_8$

Tags: permutation-groups, algebraic-graph-theory

Is there any simple graph $\Gamma$ with 16 vertices with full automorphism group $G$ such that $H\cong Q_8$ be a semiregular normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: $Q_8$ has outer automorphisms of order 2. So you can extend $Q_8$ using such an automorphism, obtaining  $G$ of order 16...

I hope it is not your homework. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I want to be $G$ as full automorphism group of a graph with 16 vertices. So I change my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example.

Adjacency matrix:

$ \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
0&1&1&0&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&0&0&0&0\\1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0&1&0\\1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&1&1&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\\0&0&1&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0&1&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0&1&0&0 \end{array} \right]$

Neighbours of each vertex:

$  \begin{array}{c|ccccc}
1&2&3&5&6&7\\
2&1&4&5&6&8\\
3&1&7&9&10&11\\
4&2&8&9&10&12\\
5&1&2&11&13&15\\
6&1&2&12&14&16\\
7&1&3&10&13&14\\
8&2&4&9&13&14\\
9&3&4&8&11&16\\
10&3&4&7&12&15\\
11&3&5&9&15&16\\
12&4&6&10&15&16\\
13&5&7&8&14&15\\
14&6&7&8&13&16\\
15&5&10&11&12&13\\
16&6&9&11&12&14 \end{array} $

It is a Cayley graph on the semidihedral group of order 16. In fact, it is a graphical regular representation, so the full automorphism group acts regularly on the vertices. Note that the semidihedral group of order 16 has a (normal) subgroup isomorphic to the quaternion group.